# Ruby on Rails Stripe, setting default amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Trying to implement Stripe into my app, but my understanding of Ruby/Rails' syntax is, while functional, still very basic. How should I express a default amount? I'm being prompted to "create a Amount class and its default class method, which should return the number you wish to charge, in pennies. One such value might be 15_00, for fifteen dollars." Thanks in advance for the help!

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def create

    # Creates a Stripe Customer object, for associating
    # with the charge
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: current_user.email,
      card: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    # Where the real magic happens
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id, # Note -- this is NOT the user_id in your app
      amount: Amount.default,
      description: "BigMoney Membership - #{current_user.email}",
      currency: 'usd'
    )

    flash[:success] = "Thanks for all the money, #{current_user.email}! Feel free to pay me again."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user) # or wherever

  # Stripe will send back CardErrors, with friendly messages
  # when something goes wrong.
  # This `rescue block` catches and displays those errors.
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

  def new
    @stripe_btn_data = {
      key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
      description: "BigMoney Membership - #{current_user.name}",
      amount: Amount.default
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: have you added method to the `amount` model. named `default`.?

Comment: i don't have a model named default/amount. I'm not exactly certain but I believe these methods work from the Stripe gem

Comment: you are trying to do `Amount.default` which will try to fetch `default` from amount model. set the default amount value somewhere. may be as `Constant` in any related model. or `app_config.yml` if you want to have default amount based on environment and fetch from there. but you need to set that value somewhere bcoz stripe expect amount to be passed and that is what you are going to handle in code as some logic.

Comment: thank you. When the prompt asked to create the class, I didn't make the connection to make the model. My understanding of the relationship between class and model is still not up to par I suppose. That said, I created the model and method for default and am still getting an 'undefined method 'default' error' though. I'll create a new question for this problem

Comment: perfect.:) still i wont suggest you to create model just for one function. rather  add to some other related model and fetch from there or other suggestions i pasted in above comment. All the best.:)